# ¿Cómo hacer un menú lateral para filtar en un recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estoy haciendo una app de Android y me gustaría meter un "menú" lateral desde la derecha para dar opciones de filtrado y que según lo que elija se filtre en el RecyclerView que tira de Firebase.
No encuentro nada por internet que me pueda servir, y me gustaría saber si por aquí sabriais cómo hacerlo. Os adjunto unos pantallazos de una app que lo hace a cómo lo quiero implementar. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al pulsar en el botón Filtrar aparece la segunda imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Hola AnnaPS, tal y como está redactada la pregunta, es demasiado amplia y le falta algo de información: ¿Qué lenguaje de programación usas? ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento? ¿Con qué dificultades o errores te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: Buenas! El lenguaje es java y XML, estoy programando para android. Por el momento no intente nada al respecto porque no sé cómo empezar ...

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas parecido y lo que mejor se adaptaria al filtro que quieres implementar es un MultiSelectionSpinner o MultiSpinner. Se quedaria como un menu emergente con una lista multiseleccion. Incluso podrias poner items desplegables.
Aqui tienes unos ejemplos:

https://asnehal.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/multi-select-drop-down-list-in-android/

https://trinitytuts.com/tips/multiselect-spinner-item-in-android/

http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286

Hay varios proyectos similares en GitHub y tutoriales, buscalos en la web.

Aqui tienes unos videos para que te hagas una idea de lo que te digo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZxVIE9-_G8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LuDC7Duvd5A

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Al final optamos por usar un botón de "lupa" y usar un fragment dialog con spinners para el filtro. aún así gracias por el interés. Un saludo.

Comment: Perdona, no habia visto la fecha, :)

Answer (score -1):

Aquí le mostraré un pequeño ejemplo, adaptelo a sus necesidades:

**DrawerLayout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:gravity="right"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
     tools:openDrawer="right">

     <include 
         layout="@layout/app_bar_main" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView 
         android:id="@+id/nav_view"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="right" 
         android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
         app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"       
         app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Menú**:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/account"
        android:title="First Item"></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/filter"
        android:title="Second Item"></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/human"
        android:title="Third Item"></item>
</group>
```

Y luego agregue a su actividad antes de `setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);`:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
}
```

> Nota: Esto solo es posible en API 17+

**Resultado**:

[image: Drawer]

[image: Drawer2]

> Fuente SO: [Right to left navigation drawer menu using android design support library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33576473/8933039)

No comprendo como dice que no encuentra nada por internet sobre este tema, cuando hay un montón de información, mire algunos enlaces de interés aquí:

> - [How to create a custom navigation drawer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23632492/8933039)
> - [Use Custom Layout in NavigationDrawer With Header And list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33464416/8933039)
> - [Align custom view to left of navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48684621/8933039)
> - [How to create a simple divider in the new NavigationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30625471/8933039)
> - [AndroidSwipeLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout)

Creo que con esto tiene como comenzar a desarrollar su aplicación, solo debe adaptarlo a como desee usarlo, Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias! Le echaré un ojo y le comento!

Comment: @AnnaPS si le ha servido de ayuda, considere votar a favor, saludos!

Comment: Por el momento lo estoy valorando, creo que no me va a servir del todo.. :( por eso aún no valoré.